# How to cleanup Homebrew references in PATH

Tags: homebrew

After migrating a previous MacOS install from an Intel-based Mac to an M1-based Mac, I have multiple references to Homebrew in my PATH:

```
❯ which -a brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

The first one is the one I want and I know the line that adds it in my `.zshrc` file.

As for the other two, I understand these to be relicts of the previous install. Also included in `.zshrc`is the following line:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I am assuming that this also includes Homebrew under `/usr/local/bin/brew`. If so:

1. Is there any way to exclude this?
2. Is this required at all? (I read somewhere that the old Intel-based install may still be used in the context of Rosetta.)
3. If it should be kept, how would I find out which configuration causes this to be included in PATH twice?

Running `grep /usr/local/bin .*` only yields `.zshrc`as a (relevant) result.

Comment: Have you grepped all of the dot files in your home?  `grep homebrew .*`?

Comment: Thanks , @TimRoberts for the pointer. No I hadn't and doing so already allowed me to remove the duplicate inclusion of the proper path (`/opt/homebrew/bin/brew`). I have I'll adjust my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I now also ran `grep /usr/local/bin /etc/*`, which yielded an entry in `/etc/paths`. After removing `/usr/local/bin` from the export statement in my `.zshrc` file, this is what I get:

```
❯ which -a brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```